# Set Azure Host/Function Key via ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I've found several resources on the web describing how to retrieve a function/host key for an Azure Function, however, I have not been able to come across anything that will allow an ARM template to set/add the function or host key.  Is this possible in the current version of Azure Functions?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not.

Comment: Thanks @kamo - doesn't look like it is and that sucks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is now supported and possible, see: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3994#issuecomment-472108298